# how to use python lambda in this case

Tags: python, lambda

Short question: im trying to create a color from existing color by subtracting 10 from each channel if the value is greater than 0, is there a short way of writing this? I don't know how to use lambda in this case, can someone tell me?

```
self.color = [color[x]-10 if lambda x: color[x]>0 for x in range(0,3)]
```

Edit: all the other channels in newly created color should be equal to 0

Comment: Shouldn't you subtract 10 only if value is grater or equal 10? Otherwise, you'll get negative values...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you only can substract 10 if the final value is greater than 0, otherwise you would get negative values.

You could do it like this:

```
[color[x]-10 if color[x]>10 else color[x] for x in range(0,3)]
```

Or more simply, as you don't have to use indices:

```
color = [5, 14, 12]
[c-10 if c>10 else c for c in  color]
# 5, 4, 2
```

If you meant to cut the values to 0, you could do:

```
color = [5, 14, 12]
[c-10 if c>10 else 0 for c in color]
# [0, 4, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a lambda?

```
self.color = [color[x]-10 for x in range(0,3) if color[x]>0]
```

Or even better:

```
self.color = [col-10 for col in color if col>0]
```

Comment: i thought lambda is like a short function to use if I needed one, didn't know you could use if in list comprehension

Comment: It's in the documentation!

Comment: I must've missed it